# Form-data in next js

Tags: next.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I am a new to  NEXT JS. and I am trying to send some form-data from client to NEXTJS API. I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a few days. There were a few explanation about this problem, but  i can't quite understand. I would be grateful, if someone could tell me what i am doing wrong and why form-data doesn't seem to work in NEXTJS.

Here is my code.

=============== CLIENT SIDE. =============================

```
const buttonHandler = (e) =\> {
e.preventDefault();
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("myImage", imageInput);
formData.append("title", title);
formData.append("description", description);

async function postData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/requests/postdata",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        body: formData,
      }
    );
    console.log(response, "Successfully sent the data to the backend!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e, "Getting an error!");
  }
}

postData();

};
```

================ In NEXT API ==========================

```
import connectMongoose from "../../../utils/connectMongoose";

import middlewareHandler from "../../../middleware/middlewareHandler";
import Post from "../../../models/posts";

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export default middlewareHandler.post(async (req, res, next) =\> {
    await connectMongoose();
    console.log("Connected to the database (upload)!");

    try {
        const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        myImage: req.file.path,
        description: req.body.description,
    });
    const savePost = await post.save();

    res.status(200).send(savePost);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, "Error is occured!");
        res.status(500).send(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. NextJs is pushing to use server actions with `form action={handleSubmit}` which does give a FormData object.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the new FormData() is not supported by Nextjs App. Even though it works perfectly on the pages directory.

My way around it is to use the state to manage the fields and then later stringify.

I believe the future update will correct the bug with FormData().

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const json = JSON.stringify(formData);
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/upload", json, {
        headers,
      });

      console.log("Response:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Image Upload and JSON Data</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="title"
            name="title"
            value={formData.title}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
          <textarea
            id="description"
            name="description"
            value={formData.description}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="image"
            name="image"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={handleFileChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageUpload;
```